# Android - Is it safe to assuming MotionEvent.ACTION_UP will 100% mean a user has touched view?

Tags: android, touch

I have a view (WebView to be specific). In that view, I have something like:

```
setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            //user has clicked
        }
    }
});
```

will this 100%, ALWAYS guarantee me that the user has tapped/clicked on the view? If not, under what cases would this not guarantee me a click??

I want to intercept all user "clicks". think of "clicking" like you would "click" a button, but just on a mobile device. Imagine this code being called 100 million times by different devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that while MotionEvent.ACTION_UP won't always be called when the touch ends (as mentioned here: [ACTION_UP not always called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928972/android-multitouch-action-up-not-always-called)), it's certainly safe to assume that a user has touched the screen.  That's how the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_UP) describes it, IMO:

> A pressed gesture has finished, the motion contains the final release
>   location as well as any intermediate points since the last down or
>   move event.

Comment: AHHHHH i see. so basically, let's say i have a small banner ad (it's a webview), and i touch initially, but then move out of banner with my finger... the ACTION_CANCEL should be called?

Comment: I can say it "should" be called.  It may not be for obvious reasons, but most likely, it will.  This is common handling for clickable UI elements.  Try clicking a button in Windows, for instance, and then mousing off.  Or a link in your browser.

Answer (score 2):

`MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` is when you lift up your finger from the screen. You can be sure the user has touches a view once the onTouch is called.

Comment: sorry, i meant "clicked". i mis-typed the question heading. would this answer still hold? by 100% i do actually mean 100%. 100% of all device types...etc.

Comment: @DavidT. sorry for the late answer. try ACTION_CANCEL